# What does "= 0" mean in Python?

Tags: python

I was doing an online course and when one of the lessons kind of lost me. Maybe I just don't remember it, but what does the "= 0" mean in the following program? I can't find any clue for it in my notes and the instructor doesn't explain it here.

```
**count = 0**
**total = 0**
inFile = open('grades.txt', 'r')
grade = inFile.readline()
while (grade):
    print(grade)
    count = count+1
    total = total + int(grade)
    grade = inFile.readline()
average = total / count
print("Average: " + str(average))
```

I feel like I'm forgetting something fundamental here.

Comment: Did you add those stars yourself? Are you asking what `count = 0` means?

Comment: you should read a basic tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html

Answer (score 5):

The = operator is called the "assignment" operator. Now, plenty of people on stackoverflow are going to tell you to do your assignment yourself, but I honestly feel for you since this is such a basic question.

It's being set to 0 since later, operations like `count = count + 1` require `count` to have a value to begin with. Adding + 1 to `None` doesn't work nicely, and even if it did, it's just nice when reading code to see variables declared in advance.

Comment: I'm glad you helped OP with the basics instead of just down voting and calling him a noob.

Comment: Thank you! That explanation sums things up perfectly. Looks like I really did miss something fundamental after all.

Answer (score 1):

It is settings the variable value to zero

```
 x = 0
```

Means set the value of x to zero.

Comment: It actually means giving the *name* x to the *value* zero.

Comment: It's still not accurate. In Python, you cannot "set" a value to zero, because zero *is* the value, and it is immutable. By saying `x = 0` you remove the name `x` from whatever it was before and attach it to the number zero instead.

Comment: There was a good talk about this topic at this year's PyCon. It is available on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns).